# Spring Boot Static folder Urls Rewritten When I Add a Path Parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot, and I have been tracking down an issue this afternoon.

Am I seeing a bug? Or is the browser remapping the relative request when it doesn't get a response based on the original include?

In an @Controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value="/chart", method=RequestMethod.GET) //This works fine
```

Retrieves src/main/resources/static/js and css folder just fine, but when I change it to

```
@RequestMapping(value="/chart/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)//This remaps relative js/static folder calls
```

to have a path parameter, all of my relative js calls end up mapped to

```
http://localhost:8080/root-url/chart/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js
```

INSTEAD of

```
http://localhost:8080/root-url/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js
```

My JS includes look like this in both views...

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Should path parameters work with the static mapping for Spring Boot?

I am using Thymeleaf templates in Spring Boot

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have a directory for

```
src/main/resources/static/js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's anything to do with Boot. If you want a URL link to be relative to the root context, not the current page, you need to specify the path correctly. Thymeleaf has a '@' prefix/function (so something like `<script th:src="@{/js/...}"...`). Other template engines do the same thing with a different syntax. Looks at the docs for the engine.

Comment: Boot is supposed to handle the static folder correctly so you don't have to do that.  http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

Comment: Not true, unless I misunderstand the question. The thymeleaf "@" syntax gives you a link relative to the server. Nothing in Boot per se can do that.

Comment: Still a little weird why you don't have to do that for a /chart call, but you do have to use the tag for /chart/{id} call